# Report Builder Expression with a '

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I have this field called series that has this expression in it, what does the ' mean in this context?

=(Fields!PropertyID.Value)
'=IIF(Parameters!CombineProperties.Value = TRUE AND (Fields!Campus.Value<>""),Fields!Campus.Value,Fields!PropertyName.Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an SSRS expression for a label or variable that is parsed at runtime in an ssrs report. The gist here is :

The starting `=(Fields!PropertyID.Value)` does not make sense as you can't set variables that way, however, after the ' it goes like this:

```
var result=null;
if (CombineProperties && Campus.Length > 0) 
    result=Campus
else
   result=PropertyName
```

After reading your post again, I think you are trying to `Concatenate` strings. Is this your end goal?

```
=CSTR(Fields!PropertyID.Value) + IIF((Parameters!CombineProperties.Value = True) AND (Fields!Campus.Value<>""), Fields!Campus.Value,Fields!PropertyName.Value)
```

**Update**

Doh!, I am rusty on VB.  I believe apostrophe comments out a line. Everything after ' is ignored. DOH!

Comment: I did not write it but based on the other fields in this report it was not concatenating. Other fields have the concatenation like how you just did above, that I understand. But the ' in there just made no sense. Another like this one is , `Fields!Consumption_Graph.Value
'IIF(Fields!Consumption_Graph.Value > REPORTITEMS!Textbox305.Value, REPORTITEMS!Textbox305.Value,Fields!Consumption_Graph.Value)` This just does not make sense to me.

Comment: doh! I think that is a comment. That part of the expression is commented out